# How to append radians( if sin( or cos( or tan( is found in a string?

Tags: python, calculator

Basically, if the user types sin( or cos( or tan(:
Return sin(radians( or cos(radians( or tan(radians( respectively

Ex:
Input: tan(sin(30))
Output: tan(radians(sin(radians(30))))

Comment: What is the meaning of `tan(radians(sin(radians(30))))`? It makes no sense. Are you sure you want that kind of substitution?

Comment: DYZ, It will, Step1. Convert 30 to radians.  Step2.sin of what it got in 1. Step3. Convert what it got in 2  to radians. Step4. Tan of result

Comment: You cannot convert the results of any trig function to radians because the result is not an angle.

Answer (score 1):

This might help:

```
if user_input[:3].lower() in ['sin','cos','tan']:
    output = user_input[:4] + 'radians(' + user_input[4:] + ')'
```

Answer (score 1):

You need substitution via a regular expression:

```
pattern = r"((?:tan\(|cos\(|sin\()+)([^)]+)"
sub = r"\1radians(\2)"
re.sub(pattern, sub, "sin(30)")
#'sin(radians(30))'
re.sub(pattern, sub, "sin(cos(30))")
#'sin(cos(radians(30)))'
```

The first group `"\1"` represents the function name, the second group `"\2"` represents the argument in the parentheses.

Answer (score 1):

Doing without regex

**Code**

```
import math

# Enter expression
s = input('Input expression')

# Find desired function in expression
# i.e. string before first paren
func = s[:s.find("(")].strip()

# Find degrees in expression
# i.e. string between parens
degrees = float(s[s.find("(")+1:s.find(")")])

# Convert to radians (needed by trigonometric functions)
radians = math.radians(degrees)

# Creates data structures allowing to select function to apply
func_names = ['sin', 'cos', 'tan']            # function names
functions = [math.sin, math.cos, math.tan]    # functions

try:
    index = func_names.index(func)            # index of function
    answer = functions[index](radians)        # with index == 0, will have math.sin(radians)
    print(answer)

except ValueError:
    print(f'Function (func) not implemented') # func not in list
```

**Alternative: using dictionary rather than try/catch**

As suggested by  acw1668 in comments

```
# ...code above before try/catch block

# Dictionary with key value pairs of name:function
# This creates {'sin': math.sin, 'cos': math.cos, 'tan': math.tan}
funcs = {k:f for k, f in zip(func_names, functions)}


if func in funcs:
    print(funcs[func](radians))
else:
    print(f'Sorry, function {func} not implemented')
```

Comment: It is easily to use `dict`: `func_names = {'sin': math.sin, 'cos': math.cos, 'tan': math.tan}`.  Then `if func in func_names: result = func_names[func](radians)`.

Comment: @acw1668--thought of that as an alternative.  Guess I should add that alternative answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
from math import radians, sin, cos, tan

eval_string = "cos(tan(30)"

for i in re.findall("(cos\(|sin\(|tan\()", eval_string):
    if i == "cos(":
        eval_string = re.sub("(cos\()","cos(radians(", eval_string)
    elif i == "sin(":
        eval_string = re.sub("(sin\()","sin(radians(", eval_string)
    elif i == "tan(":
        eval_string = re.sub("(tan\()","tan(radians(", eval_string)
     
print(eval_string)
print(eval(eval_string))
```

I did got the solution, with only the exception of brackets at the end, whickh can be easily solved, it's a bit long though

I thank everyone who answered and inspired me to get to the right answer.
Thanks